# Memory address of Python class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, memory-address

Been a reader for some months but this is my first post (open to feedback in improving posting). I have gone through the fundamentals of Python and OOP and want to understand memory better:

```
class Foo(): pass


class Bar():

    def __repr__(self):
        standard_ouput = f'<{__name__}.{type(self).__name__} object at {hex(id(self))}> (override)'

        return standard_ouput


f = Foo()
b = Bar()

print(Foo())
print(f)
print(Bar())
print(b)
```

The above code outputs some variation of:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1079973c8>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x107997358>
<__main__.Bar object at 0x1079973c8> (override)
<__main__.Bar object at 0x107997400> (override)
```

1). Why do `Foo()` and `Bar()` both point to the same memory address? Is this something to do with overriding the `__repr__` method of `Bar`?

2). Did the way I asked Q1 above make sense (trying to get better at CS terminology)?

Comment: Hint: After Python is done with `print(Foo())`, it throws the `Foo` object away.

Comment: If the lifetime of the objects don't overlap, they can be at the same address.

Comment: These aren't class objects, they are instance objects.